# R font in latex

Tags: fonts, r

I wanted to describe some R packages in latex document and I'm wondering what font (and how to use it like 5 times) is usually used in names of packages?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. What exactly do you mean? Usually packages are displayed using a monospaced font, so `\texttt{package-name}` should do what you want, or better, create a macro for packages: `\newcommand\pkg[1]{\texttt{#1}}` and then if you need to change them all, you only need to change the definition.